# Magmi bulk image import (associate by sku)

Tags: image, magento, import, magmi, skus

I have a folder with about 6000 images, all named according to the sku being imported in magento via csv. I have installed magmi and the Image Attributes Processor. If I put these images in media/import, will they associate themselves by sku, or do I have to do something specific in my configuration/scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Magmi plugin "Image attributes processor v1.0.25"
enable import images to magmi,
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

You need only to configure your folder in image module.

configuration:
Image search path: relative path for your image, for your folder will be "media/import" (check your magmi "Filesystem Path to magento directory", if you have "magento_folder/magmi" Filesystem Path to magento directory should be "../../")

columns in CSV file must be named "image","small_image","thumbnail" (case sensitive!!)
in this columns will be values like "imagename.jpg".

Thats all

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My csv does not have these columns yet. I have uploaded all the images to magento_docroot/media/import, and it is saying no `image attributes found in datasource, disabling image processor`. I am guessing because these columns do not exist in the csv. If I copy the sku column and find a way to append .jpg to all the rows, I can achieve this using this method? I was hoping there would just be a way to match the images to the sku column. I haven't used this tool before, but I like it way better than Magento default importer!

Comment: no need for this. use value replacer to create virtual image column :),attribute to replace : image, new value for image : {item.sku}.jpg , and you're done !

Comment: very nice! Didn't see that little gem in the documentation.

Comment: Any idea of the syntax I can use to create a new column based on the sku column? I have tried a few things and I am still getting the datasource error.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out by putting image in the first form field and {item.sku}.jpg in the second, thanks again!