# magento import csv using dataflow-profile image does not exists?

Tags: php, magento, magmi

My current Magento version is 1.8.1.0.

I am trying to import products using **dataflow - profile**. When I uploaded the csv as mentioned below and ran the profile, I got the following error.

> error image does not exists.

I've placed images into `media/import/product/p1.jpg` folder.

My media folder permission is 777.

And I wrote image path in `csv` file like,

```
image               small_image          thumbnail
/product/p1.jpg   /product/p1.jpg    /product/p1.jpg
```

where did I mistake here? Please help.

Comment: Use magmi project. It is very fast and imports images without any glitches. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888120/magmi-bulk-image-import-associate-by-sku

Comment: @DushyantJoshi where i can download this module. please give me a llink.

Comment: GO through this wiki. http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki. It may take some time to understand but it is worthy. You can download Magmi from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: You might need extra utility plugins from here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

Comment: @DushyantJoshi i can't found how to install extra plugins please help thank you.

Comment: This link provides in detail installation of Magmi & its plugins. https://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer

Comment: Let me know if are you stuck somewhere. And more importantly its always useful to have backup before you install anything